# Checkboxtype doesn't change value according to the related object

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox

I have a class Measure with a boolean property named "isShared"

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MeasureRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("name", message = "This value is already used")
 */
class Measure
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_shared", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isShared;
}
```

And a form in which the value of the value of the isShared property should be changed through a checkbox.

```
class MeasureType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('isShared', CheckboxType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Shared',
                'attr' => array(
                    'data-on-color' => 'primary',
                    'data-off-color' => 'default'
                )
            ));
}
```

The problem is that the rendered html is always

```
<input type="checkbox" id="measure_isShared" name="measure[isShared]" data-on-color="primary" data-off-color="default" value="1" /> Shared</label>
```

not taking into account the value of the property in the object. When I pass to the form a Measure object with the property isShared set to false, the value of the input is always 1.

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, value in checkboxes **should** always be `1`.

In fact, if unchecked, your browser would skip sending the property `mesure[isShared]` altogether and your `FormType` would just be able to conclude that user did not check the field. Not sending the value and sending `0` makes all the difference

Think of think a mean to transfer some arbitrary info (not just binary `0`/`1`) to a server. In case of, say, `choice` (with `expanded` and `multiple` of course), `value` would contain those values, but only some of these would be submitted back to server.

Hint: have you tried dumping the `Measure` object once you submit the form?

Hope this helps...